# Drawing a circle on a particular pixel of image

Tags: android

I have drawn a circle in a canvas with image in it on click event in one activity. And I have taken the x and y coordinates of that circle. In another activity i want to draw the same circle at the same position but the image size is not same so it is pointing to different position. So, how can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new position of circle (newX, newY) must move at same ratio that image size change.

```
newX = oldX * (newImageWidth / oldImageWidth)
newY = oldY * (newImageHeight / oldImageHeight)
```

You may want to change the size of the circle same way.